Speeding up the Source Reader
The idea is to make the IMFSourceReader return samples faster in order to enhance video editing. It may occur for example that I have to render to the preview 3-4 layers (say, in a video wall) and I want to speed up the result of ReadSample as much as possible.
I' ve tried the rate control. The functions indicate that "thin" mode is supported along with a rate of 2.0, for example:
    CComPtr<IMFRateSupport> rs;
    CComPtr<IMFRateControl> rc;
    r->GetServiceForStream((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, MF_RATE_CONTROL_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFRateSupport), (void**)&rs);
    r->GetServiceForStream((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, MF_RATE_CONTROL_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFRateControl), (void**)&rc);
    float pf = 0;
    auto hr = rs->IsRateSupported(true, 1.0f, &pf);
    hr = rs->IsRateSupported(false, 1.0f, &pf);
    hr = rs->IsRateSupported(true, 2.0f, &pf);
    hr = rs->IsRateSupported(false, 2.0f, &pf);
    hr = rc->SetRate(true, 2.0f);

All calls return S_OK, but I don't see any difference in the renderer samples when I get them through the Source Reader.
I 've also tried to skip manually, in a for loop, samples that do not have the 'MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint' attribute. But I found out that all the samples I get from the reader do indeed have the attribute set:
auto u1 = MFGetAttributeUINT32(pSample, MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, FALSE);
if (!u1) { never enters here }

What are my options?
Best,

By using the rate control service, an application can implement fast forward and reverse playback. In my opinion, you couldn't use rate control to speed  up the result of ReadSample.
You could try to use the Source Reader in Asynchronous Mode

@Jeaninez-MSFT my problem is not to avoid blocking the caller because it already runs in a background thread. The problem is to make it generate the sample faster, perhaps skipping the delta frames or lowering the quality etc.

Try to use DXVA with the Source Reader.
The Source Reader is compatible with Microsoft DirectX Video Acceleration (DXVA) 2.0 for hardware accelerated video decoding. Refer to the Doc:Hardware Acceleration
